# A GUI based Java multi-thread file server and client

Tags: java, file, server, client, transfer

I was doing an assignment to create a UI based client to send and display files. The server will both send and receive the files (just like file upload and download to ftp).

Now I have only two problems:

1. if we send a file to server for storing the file on disk from client it writes data to file and then stores file with name as null .(I know that this is because I am not sending file name to server with which to store the file). I want to send the server both name of file and contents of the file. how should I do it?
2. Another thing that the client and server both have File Send and File Receive methods which run in Thread. when The client requests file the File Send of server should send it and when the client uploads file the File receive of server should accept it, but if I just start both the threads in MainMethod one of them says that the connection is refused.(As the File receive means that the File send of client should run before file receive of server and vice versa) how should I do it?

Main Method of CLIENT

```
public class MainMethod  {
    public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception {
        new FileScreen();
        new FileReceive().start();
        new FileSend().start();

    }   
}
```

Main Method of SERVER

```
public class MainMethod {
    public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException {
        new FileSend().start();
        new FileReceive().start();
    }
}
```

Finally FileSend of Client

```
public void run () {
    socket = serverSocket.accept ();    
    dis = new DataInputStream (socket.getInputStream ());
    dos = new DataOutputStream (socket.getOutputStream ());
    dos.writeUTF(Filename); //tried to send filename to server 

    :does not work
        
    bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
    while ( (data1 = bufferedReader.readLine ()) != null ){
        if ( flag == 0 ){
            fileData = data1;
            flag = 1;
        }else {
            fileData = fileData+"\n"+data1;
        }
    }
    bufferedReader.close ();
    dos.writeUTF (fileData);  //send file contents to server
}
```

File Receive of SERVER

```
public void run () {
    downloadFileName = dis.readUTF();   //this line should read name :- not working
    downloadFileContent = dis.readUTF (); // this line works fine in absence of above line
    BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("/home/user/Client&Server/ServerReceive/"+downloadFileName));
    bufferedWriter.write (downloadFileContent);
    bufferedWriter.close ();
}
```

Comment: Step back for a second. You need to devise a "protocol" which defines the series of commands which need to be issued that will allow both the server a client to be able to agree on the proper communications. For example, you might send "name" followed by the file name, "size" followed by the file size and "content" followed by the file content (possible line delimited). This way, the server would "wait" till it gets the "name", "size" and then "content" - then it knows what to do. Of course, I would use base64 encoding and just it all up in JSON - but that's me

Comment: As to you second question - it's a bit odd to have both the client and server in the same project. Normally you'd have the server acting as a single project and the client as another. This way, you need to ensure that the server is up and running BEFORE the client is started

Comment: actually both are different projects but for convenience I gave the code snippets together. As for Protocol, I didn't quite get you can you please elaborate. A rough code snippet or something would be helpful else just an explanation is also fine.

Comment: I have thought of sending the server a text or something to notify which FileSend or FileReceive should run when . Currently trying that out .Do you mean the similar thing in case of Protocol? Thank You

Comment: Thank you guys. I solved the problem partially by your suggestion @MadProgrammer and by modifying an old piece of code I had lying around. Thanks anyways